# Build Android app using distant computer

Tags: android, android-studio, build

I'm currently working on a big app and it takes ages to the machine to build it. I'd like to know if it's possible to deport the building process on a distant and more powerful computer without leaving Android Studio? If not is there any way to faster the building process?

Comment: you want megs of files to transfer and get it back and make it reflect the new build changes back into your current process , sounds like a overhead and requires support for network errors  and preview releases and much more and apparently something like this won't be freely available :P

Answer (score 1):

- you could use a special flavor or build type which uses a *higher* `minSdk`

  `productFlavors {
  dev {
    dimension "stage"
    minSdkVersion 21
    versionNameSuffix "-dev"
    applicationIdSuffix '.dev'
    ...
  }`
- increase heap size

  `org.gradle.jvmargs = -Xmx2048m`

and much more: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/optimize-your-build.html

Answer (score 0):

Sure.  You don't think release builds are generally made on the developer's desktop PCs, do you?  Generally they're done via command line builds on a build server so everything can be scripted.  No reason you can't do the same for your local build.  However you'll need to copy over the files in your local somehow, build, then bring the resulting apk back.  You'll have a couple of hours of scipting work to set it all up.

Comment: Do you have any tools or guidelines that I could use?